# Openerp 7 - Create Graph View

Tags: odoo

I am using Openerp 7 and I want to display a Graph View with `type='line'`. My problem is, I don't know how this should work.

I have a Class with an Date:

```
 class service(osv.osv):
    _name="my.name"
    _columns={
      'date' : fields.date(...)
    }
```

Now I will create an Line Graph that shows me the Count of Services from one Week.

```
<record id="service_action_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">fenecon.service.graph</field>
  <field name="model">fenecon.service</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <graph string="contacts" version="7.0" type="bar">
        <field name="creation_date" type="col" interval="day" group="True" />
        <field name="id" type="row" operator="+" />
    </graph>
  </field>
</record>
```

But I only get a Point at `0,0`.

How do Graphs work? The documentation isn't helpfull.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to specify the type of the greaph : `Line` and not `Bar`.

Then you need to set the interval as `week`.

The `create_date` field must have a `row` type.

Finaly the `id` field must be declared in your model (the class).

```
  <record id="service_action_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">fenecon.service.graph</field>
  <field name="model">fenecon.service</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <graph string="Semoule" type="line" >
                     <field name="create_date" interval="week" type="row"/>
                     <field name="id" type="measure"/>                   
                </graph>
            </field>
   </record>
```

Hope this will help you.